# Pseudoselectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this in my JavaScript:

```
var id = "\#mode";
if (visible){
    $("a[href^=\/\""+id+"\"]").addClass('w--current');
} else {
    $("a[href^=\/\""+id+"\"]").removeClass('w--current');
}                               }
```

I know that you can do something like this in CSS as well, so for instance

```
a[class^=myClass] {
    display: none;
}
```

should trigger on every `a`-tag, which has a class starting with `myClass`.

However, does this apply to the href attribute?

This here is the error printed in the console:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href^=/"#mode"]

Comment: That selector is ill-formed. Why does it contain a slash after the equal sign?

Comment: I assume the href value starts with backslash.

Comment: btw you want to use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Comment: @moonwave99 Please add a reason why toggleClass is better than current implementation.

Comment: Because `$("a[href^=\/\""+id+"\"]").toggleClass('w--current', visible);` is shorter and more readable, at least to my eye ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your escape sequence is the problem, you have an extra `\/` in your script

```
$('a[href^="' + id + '"]').addClass('w--current');
```